# Como adicionar propriedades a componentes WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wpf

Posso usar como exemplo o `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`. Como faço para adicionar mais comportamentos e propriedades à ele?

Num contexto real, gostaria que o componente `TextBox` tivesse uma propriedade booleana `HasErrors`, que se estivesse como verdadeiro, deixaria o componente em vermelho, até que tal erro fosse corrigido. Sei que existem formas de fazer isso com `Triggers`, mudando o `Background`, porém gostaria de personalizar o próprio componente.

Como personalizar com componente WPF? A forma mais próxima de fazer isso seria somente criando um novo componente que herdasse do `TextBox`, como faço isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o que pretende é ter um TextBox com uma propriedade nova, a forma é herdar de TextBox e adicionar a nova propriedade como uma DependencyProperty.

Exemplo onde é adicionada a propriedade HasErrors que quando `true` coloca o Background a vermelho.

```
public class HasErrorsTextBox : TextBox
{
    private Brush NoErrorsBackgroundColor { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "HasErrors",
          typeof(bool),
          typeof(HasErrorsTextBox),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnHasErrorsChanged)
        );

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasErrorsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasErrorsProperty, value); }
    }


    private static void OnHasErrorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = d as HasErrorsTextBox;
        if (textBox.NoErrorsBackgroundColor == null)
        {
            textBox.NoErrorsBackgroundColor = textBox.Background;
        }

        textBox.Background = (bool)e.NewValue ? Brushes.Red : textBox.NoErrorsBackgroundColor;
    }

}
```

Forma de usar:

```
<local:HasErrorsTextBox Text="HasErrorsTextBox" HasErrors="True"/>
```

Outra abordagem é criar uma *Attached Property*. Esta abordagem permite criar uma propriedade que pode ser associada(*Attached*) a um mesmo grupo de componentes.
Neste exemplo, ela poderia ser aplicada a qualquer componente que tenha a propriedade Background(qualquer tipo que herde de Control).

Exemplo implementando uma *Attached Property*:

```
public static class MyAttachedProperties
{
    private static Brush NoErrorsBackgroundColor { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "HasErrors",
          typeof(bool),
          typeof(MyAttachedProperties),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnHasErrorsChanged)
        );

    public static bool GetHasErrors(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(HasErrorsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHasErrors(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(HasErrorsProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnHasErrorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as Control;
        if (control == null)
        {
            throw new
                InvalidOperationException("Esta propriedade apenas pode ser aplicada a objectos do tipo Control");
        }

        if (NoErrorsBackgroundColor == null)
        {
            NoErrorsBackgroundColor = control.Background;
        }

        control.Background = (bool)e.NewValue ? Brushes.Red : NoErrorsBackgroundColor;

    }

}
```

Forma de usar:

```
<TextBox Text="AttachedProperty" local:MyAttachedProperties.HasErrors="True"/>
```

Comment: Entendi! Com herança, tem como adicionar algo na UI? Como por exemplo, adicionar uma lupa (path ou image) no TextBox.

Comment: Nesse caso talvez o melhor é um User Control.